# Can I use sewer cleanout as washing machine water outlet

Tags: washing-machine, cleanout

I live in LA and we have a convenient sewer cleanout where I would like to place the washing machine. Is there an adapter for the cleanout to accommodate the outgoing water? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: hard to say without knowing what it is. Can you take a photo and attach it?

Answer (score 4):

Not a 100% definite answer (I am not a plumber or a code expert), but I would be concerned about a **trap**. Or rather, a lack thereof. A plumbing fixture - sink, shower, bathtub, dishwasher, laundry drain, etc. normally has a [trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(plumbing)) that fills with water and keeps sewer gas from getting into the building. A cleanout, by its nature, will likely have a straight shot down the drain pipe - i.e., you would not want to have a trap in a cleanout because it would make it much harder to clean out.

Comment: i agree with @manassehkatz ... but you could build an adapter that includes a trap

Comment: Threaded ABS fitting to fit into the cleanout, trap attached onto that and 18 inch down tube on top of the trap